# Load object with pickle on AWS ec2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pickle

I have created a Random Forest Regression model in Python and I am trying to deploy that model to an AWS Ubuntu ec2 instance.
I have done all the necessary steps to make it run on my Node.js server and it runs perfectly without any errors.

When I try to run it on the ec2 instance it runs fine until it tries to load the model which is a .sav file of my Random Forest model (saved it using Pickle). When it gets to the line of code where I load the .sav file it just doesn't respond. I tried to print stack trace with traceback but it doesn't respond so I can't see the error output.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import sys
input_data = sys.argv[1].split(",") 
regressor = pickle.load(open("./pythonScripts/"+input_data[0]+"/reg "+input_data[0]+".sav", 'rb'))
print(traceback.format_exc())
```

I have made sure the path to the .sav file is correct, I have made sure Python and all the necessary libraries are correctly installed on the instance (Sklearn, Numpy). I even print a simple text output just to make sure Python is running fine on the instance.

Everything works perfectly on my private computer which is running Windows.
Could it be that Pickle acts differently on different OS?

Comment: How large is the file you are trying to load?

Comment: @JohannBauer I am actually loading 2 objects. The Regressor is pretty big, around 1gb but the other object is small, around 30mb. I have managed to load both of them on my PC with no problem.

Comment: Does the small file load correctly? In that case you probably just need to wait longer or look into alternatives to Pickle, like MessagePack.

Comment: @JohannBauer No, the smaller file also doesn't load. Can MessagePack  load binary files saved by Pickle?